# Prove that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} P(A_{i})[P(B_{i})-(i-1) P(A_{i})]$ $\ge n P(A_{1})[\frac{1}{2}-n P(A_{1})]$

Tags: probability-theory

denote by $A_{i}$ and $B_{i}$ the events $\left\{X_{i}>n^{1 / r} \epsilon\right\}$ and $\left\{\sum_{j=1, j \neq i}^{n} X_{j}>0\right\}$ respectively, the $X_i$'s are independent and identically distributed.

Prove that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} P(A_{i})[P(B_{i})-(i-1) P(A_{i})]$ $\ge n P(A_{1})[\frac{1}{2}-n P(A_{1})]$

I attempted the following :

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{n} P(A_{i})[P(B_{i})-(i-1) P(A_{i})] & = nP(A_1)(P(B_1)-\frac{n-1}{2} P(A_1))\\
&= nP(A_1)(P(B_1)+\frac{n+1}{2}P(A_1)-nP(A_1))\\
\end{align}

can I say that $P(B_1)+\frac{n+1}{2}P(A_1) \ge \frac12$

or should this be proven differently?

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me that your inequality can't hold generally. Take $X$ to be Gaussian with variance $1$ and mean $\mu$ with $\mu<0$. Then $P(A_{1})>0$ and hence the inequality is equivalent to $P(B_{1}) + \frac{n+1}{2}P(A_{1})\geq \frac{1}{2}$ (when $P(A_{1}) = 0$, your original inequality holds). But in this case $P(B_{1})= P(Z>-\sqrt{n-1}\mu)$ with $Z$ being a standard normal so that $P(B_{1})<\frac{1}{2}-\delta$ for $n$ large. In the limit as $n$ goes to $\infty$, $\frac{n+1}{2}P(A_{1})$ goes to zero. So the reduced inequality can't hold for each $n$.